# "let json = JSON(command.arguments)" failing when built using Swift 4

Tags: swift, cordova-plugins, swifty-json

The following line in cordova plugin code written for Swift 3,
     let json = JSON(command.arguments)
is throwing error when built using swift 4.

Pls let me know what change needs to made to make it work in Swift 4.

command.arguments is of type [Any]! and it contains a String which is a json. I am unable to use String.data as it says [Any]! does not have member data

Error is
error: argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working in Swift 4? Is it a compiler error or a runtime? Can you also post a screenshot of the error as you see it so to be sure there is no misinterpretation? That would be helpful

Comment: `func authenticate(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        print("AUTHENTICATE ")
        
        self.recognitionCallbackId = command.callbackId
        var pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
        )
        
        let json = JSON(command.arguments)
        let url = json[0]["speech_to_text"][0]["credentials"]["url"].stringValue`